# Working with 1-Result-Linq with For Each? Any alternative?

Tags: vb.net, linq

If I got a Linq-Query where I am knowing that it'll return 1 result only, like this:

```
Dim result = From g In Foo.Bar
    Where g.keyID = 1
    Select g
```

...do I still have to use the For Each loop to get the values or is there anything else I could use to work with 1-result-queries?

```
For Each x In result
    TextBox1.Text = x.field1
    TextBox2.Text = x.field2
    TextBox3.Text = x.field3
Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.First`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.100).aspx)/ `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` or [`Enumerable.Single`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx)/ `Enumerable.SingleOrDefault`(if it was exceptional if  there were more than one).

```
Dim firstResult = result.FirstOrDefault()
If firstResult IsNot Nothing Then
    TextBox1.Text = firstResult.field1
    TextBox2.Text = firstResult.field2
    TextBox3.Text = firstResult.field3
End If
```

- So use `First` if it's possible that there are more than one but you want the first
- Use `Single` if you want the first but it was a bug if there were more than one
- The methods without `OrDefault` in the name will throw an exception if none was found
- The `OrDefault` methods will return the default value(`Nothing` for reference types).